# JAVA excape sequence for map key

Tags: java, escaping, java-6

please help to append " " at the start and end of **String.class** in the map using escape sequence, i not sure how to add.

```
static Map Types = new LinkedHashMap();
Types.put(String.class, new StringSerial());
```

Expected results is "String.class"

thanks

Comment: What are the key and value types of this map? And the expected result should appear where? In some kind of text output? Where is that created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> Types = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        Types.put("\"String.class\"", new Parent());

        for (Map.Entry entry : Types.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
"String.class"
```

Comment: I need a util java class to do the escape sequence, i have so many places to call the util to do the escape sequence. thanks

Comment: @Nisha can't you build it using above